# Transform linear system into a matrix form

Tags: matrix, programming, linear-algebra

I have a system of linear equations in variables $A_n$ of form:
$$
 \sum _{k=-K}^K h_k A_{n-k} J_{n-k}\left(\frac{(1-i) \text{$\eta
   $Sqrt}(n-k)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+A_n\left(\frac{(1-i) \eta  \sqrt{n-k} J_{n-1}\left(\frac{(1-i)
   \sqrt{n-k} \eta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-(n-k) J_n\left(\frac{(1-i) \sqrt{n-k} \eta
   }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)=t_n
$$
How can I transform it into a matrix form in Mathematica?
I need it to put this matrix into a Gaussian elimination procedure (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84324/29728) and get these $A_n$.
If that's important, $t_n$ is a coefficient from Fourier series $t_n=\frac{\int_0^{2 \pi } e^{-\text{in$\phi $}} t(\phi ) \, d\phi }{2 \pi }$, also $h_k=\frac{\int_0^{2 \pi } e^{-\text{ik$\phi $}} h(\phi ) \, d\phi }{2 \pi }$, and variables $A_n$ are coefficients of the Fourier series $F(r,\phi )=\sum _{n=-N}^N e^{\text{in$\phi $}} A_n J_n\left(\frac{(1-i) r \eta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: the first equation is a transformed Robin BC for PDE.

Comment: your definition of h_k is independent of k. I assume you meant to replace the variable n there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries you're right, my negligence. Done.

Answer (score 10):

I think the function you are looking for is `CoefficientArrays`; here is [its documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html).

Your system is quite complex so I will let *you* deal with its intricacies, but here is a demonstration on a toy example.

Let's define a set of linear equations in $x$, $y$, and $z$:

```
eqns = {2 x - y + 4 z == 12, 3 x + 2 y + z == 10, -y + z == 1};
```

The solutions of this system are of course $x=1, y=2, z=3$.

Once you have your system represented as a list of equations, use `CoefficientArrays` to transform them into matrix form:

```
linsystem = CoefficientArrays[eqns, {x, y, z}];
Normal@linsystem
```

> { {-12, -10, -1}, { {2, -1, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {0, -1, 1} } }

`CoefficientArrays` returns the coefficients as `SparseArray` objects, which is why I used `Normal` to visualize them as regular arrays, but you should be able to use the `SparseArray`s directly in further computation.

You can then feed those matrices to your Gaussian elimination routines, or alternatively use *Mathematica*'s built-in linear system solver, `LinearSolve`:

```
LinearSolve[#2, -#1] & @@ linsystem
```

> {1, 2, 3}

The $(-1)$ coefficient I used in the second argument to `LinearSolve` is a product of how `CoefficientArrays` interprets equations in its input, rather than plain polynomials, as mentioned in the "Details" section of the documentation.