# Problems with indexes in a Do-cycle and CoefficientArrays

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I have a system of linear equations with variables $A_n$ and need its coefficients in a matrix form ([Transform linear system into a matrix form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84454/29728)). I'm trying to do that through a `Do`-cycle and `CoefficientArrays`, however, I have mistaken somewhere

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"];
    kk = 3; (* just test values *)
    nn = 4; (* just test values *)

    eqns = {};
    (* I expect code below make a list of equations in form 
    eqns = {2 x - y + 4 z == 12, 3 x + 2 y + z == 10, -y + z == 1}; *)
    Do[
      eqns[[n]] = 
       Indexed[coefA,n] ((1 - I)/Sqrt[2] \[Eta] Sqrt[n]*
            BesselJ[n - 1, (1 - I)/Sqrt[2] \[Eta] Sqrt[n]] - 
           n BesselJ[n, (1 - I)/Sqrt[2] \[Eta] Sqrt[n]]) + 
        Sum[Integrate[h[\[Phi]]/E^Ik\[Phi], {\[Phi], 0,2*Pi}] (Indexed[coefA, n - k] BesselJ[n - k, (1 - I)/Sqrt[2] \[Eta] Sqrt[n - k]] - 
            Integrate[t[\[Phi]]/E^(I (n - k) \[Phi]), {\[Phi], 0, 
              2*Pi}] )==0, {k, -kk, kk, 1}],
      {n, 1, nn}
     ]
```

and get only following errors:

> Set::partw: Part -4 of {} does not exist. >>
>   Indexed::ind: The index 0 is not a nonzero integer. >>
>   Set::partw: Part -3 of {} does not exist. >>
>   Indexed::ind: The index 0 is not a nonzero integer. >>
>   Set::partw: Part -2 of {} does not exist. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Set::partw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>   Indexed::ind: The index 0 is not a nonzero integer. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Indexed::ind will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Then I'm taking coefficients from `eqns`, and here,probably, I'm mistaken too:

```
    nlist = Table[n, {n, -nn, nn, 1}];
    (* As a result of cycle I expect list coefAlist={Indexed[coefA, 1],Indexed[coefA, 2],...} *)
    Do[coefAlist[n] = Indexed[coefA, n], {n, nlist}]
    linsystem = CoefficientArrays[eqns, coefAlist];
```

I have no ideas how to correct this code in the proper way.

**Can smb help?**

Comment: What is the difference between this question and the last question that you linked to?

Comment: @Pickett the last question was "What functions can do that?", this one  - what I'm doing wrong with these functions, or how to code it in a better way?

Comment: So basically how to do it without using CoefficientArrays? Your first sentence is confusing in this regard ("through a Do-cycle and CoefficientArrays")

Comment: @Pickett I tender an apology, if I expressed myself with ambiguity. I've tried to apply method from the last question's answer to my system of linear equations. Nevertheless, I grappled with a problem on that way.  
In the first block code I want to make a list with equations, in the second one - take coefficients from this list into sparse array. I can set equations and variables manually for three or four of them, but I have to deal with fifty or more. I need some "automatization" with `Do`, `List` and `CoefficientArrays`, but I did it in a bad way. So I ask for suggestions.

Comment: One first, simple problem is the fact that you cannot use `Indexed` with an index value of zero; however, that happens multiple times inside your `Sum` expression. Second, you cannot construct your list `eqns` starting from an empty list and assigning values to the nonexistent parts; you have to e.g. `AppendTo` a list (may be inefficient), or use a `Reap` / `Sow` method...

Comment: @MarcoB as I understoond, inside my `Sum` coefficients with index value of zero just equate to zero, and that's not a great problem for me.  Thanks for `Reap` / `Sow` method - it's really faster!
So now I still have a question only about `CoefficientArrays`: how can I choose all coefficient $A$ with an index value $n≥|b|$ as variables? By the way, `Indexed` is still unclear for me, and WolframDocumentation is not very detailed. How to set a rule of substitution to an expression for an indexed variable? Construction of form `Indexed[x,1]=a^2` doesn't work, but what's the correct variant?